# Fetch records week wise for last one year in MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table with users data.Columns are Username,Datetime.
I need to fetch count of users weekly wise for last one year data from current date.
I wrote query to fetch last one year's record daywise but I couldn't find a way to retrieve data in weekly wise.
Below is the query to fetch data in day wise.

```
select count(Username) 
from tablename
where (Datetime > DATEADD(year,-1,GETDATE()) and Datetime< GETDATE()-1)
group by Datetime
order by Datetime asc
```

Can anyone help me to fetch the weekwise count for the same in sql server?

Comment: @ GurV sql server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TRY THIS**: you have to group by `week` so you can done in the following way:

```
SELECT COUNT(Username) 
from tablename
where (Datetime > DATEADD(year,-1,GETDATE()) and DATETIME < GETDATE()-1)
group by DATEPART(wk,[DATETIME])
order by [Datetime] ASC
```

Note: Please try to avoid `reserved words` as column name and you can enclosed existing one in `[]`.

Answer (score 1):

Use DATEPART IN GROUP BY clause.In where condition first filter one year record and then group by based on DATEPART function to get week wise count

```
SELECT COUNT(Username) , DATEPART(WEEK,Datetime) 
FROM tablename
WHERE DATEDIFF(YEAR,Datetime,GETDATE()) <= 0 AND     
DATEDIFF(YEAR,Datetime,DATEADD(YEAR,-1,GETDATE())) >= 0
GROUP BY DATEPART(WEEK,Datetime)
```

Comment: @Sulthan Allaudeen, In where condition first filter one year record and then group by based on DATEPART function to get week wise count.

Comment: Thanks, Please update the explanation in your Answer. So, that it would be useful to the future readers\

Comment: @Sulthan Allaudeen,Explanation added in answer

Comment: Great effort, appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can just change the group by and order by clause as below.

```
group by datepart(week,Datetime)
order by datepart(week,Datetime) asc
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to specify extra column, pointing which week of the year it is.
You can create it like this (I assume that you have data from more years and let's call our column `Date`):

```
CASE WHEN Date BETWEEN '2017-01-01 00:00:00.000' AND '2018-01-01 00:00:00.000'
    THEN floor(cast(datediff(dd, '2017-01-01 00:00:00.000',Date) as real) / 7)
    END AS [Week]
```

Secondly, you have to run the query:

```
SELECT COUNT(Username) FROM tablename
GROUP BY [Week]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *, WEEK(created_on) week
FROM Table_Name
WHERE created_on > DATEADD(year,-1,GETDATE())
ORDER BY week
```